# What is the best way to make the ripped part looks like a cloth texture?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, bevel, extrude

Video reference: https://cloudmails-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/tp053611_mail_apu_edu_my/EXNCEcZLKXJGkUmnUuM_0JABbdoeQBLT68Oi7_UDiMWlbA?nav=eyJyZWZlcnJhbEluZm8iOnsicmVmZXJyYWxBcHAiOiJPbmVEcml2ZUZvckJ1c2luZXNzIiwicmVmZXJyYWxBcHBQbGF0Zm9ybSI6IldlYiIsInJlZmVycmFsTW9kZSI6InZpZXciLCJyZWZlcnJhbFZpZXciOiJNeUZpbGVzTGlua0NvcHkifX0&e=aeIlly

I tried extrude, bevel and sculpt with cloth brush but doesn't get the effect I want

Comment: Hi Lucci, the video reference is fine, but it tells us what  only you _don't_ want, and the post is entirely dependent on it. This would be a great deal easier for us to help you with, if you somehow indicate what you _do_ want .. a reference or sketch. Can you also tell us whether, at any stage, the tearing itself, or the resulting rags, have to be animated? I think that would make a big difference.

Comment: If the link breaks, no one will know what the question is about, and it will be completely useless for other readers looking for an answer in the future. Add a screenshot and a brief description of what you have tried, what you want, and what doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create a black image texture that you project onto the surface and use a ripped fabric material as stencil texture to paint over:

[image]

Then use the image as factor between your 2 shaders (costume and skin):

[image]